# SQL Server subquery with top and max returning error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Why doesn't this code work? I get this error

> Error near ')'

on the last line. I cannot see where I made a syntax error (this is for SQL Server 2017).

```
DECLARE @NumRows INT;  

SELECT @NumRows = COUNT(*) / 2
FROM SAMA;

SELECT MAX(NoMonths) 
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP(@NumRows) NoMonths  
     FROM SAMA 
     ORDER BY NoMonths ASC)
```

What the query is trying to do, is to find a max of top N rows, and the N is defined in the variable.

Without `MAX`, the subquery works and returns N rows. But when I add `MAX`, it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set a table alias:

```
DECLARE @NumRows INT;

SELECT @NumRows = COUNT(*) / 2 FROM SAMA;

SELECT MAX(NoMonths) 
FROM (
  SELECT TOP(@NumRows) NoMonths  
  FROM SAMA 
  ORDER BY NoMonths ASC
) table_alias
```

Comment: it works!  unbelievable, this would be the last thing I'd have suspected. All the more, it works without even without using the alias in the MAX(column) to reference the column. 
 The more i learn, the more it seems I will never get there.  Thank you very much Sebastian.

Comment: would it be too cheeky to ask why it wanted an alias? It's not like there is another FROM that could have caused a confusion, what difference it makes if i give it a name or not? I don't think it's compulsory to give alias to a subquery, or is it?

Comment: @Lana B It's a good question.  When a subquery is used in a From clause SQL considers it a table and therefore requires a name.  Think of a spreadsheet, the columns and filters don't have to have names, but the worksheet does.  It's easy to forget (and a nuisance sometimes) but makes sense if you think about it that way.

Comment: @JJ32 thank you. I have taken this onboard and it already must have saved me time wondering why something fails, but knowing why helps.  I have learnt so much on stackoverflow this week, thank you guys for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a table alias

```
DECLARE @NumRows INT;

SELECT @NumRows = COUNT(*) / 2  FROM SAMA;

SELECT MAX(NoMonths)
FROM (SELECT TOP(@NumRows) NoMonths FROM SAMA ORDER BY NoMonths ASC) sama_alias
```

Comment: Amit, thank you for the effort. There is however, an exact same answer posted 40min before yours, thus I've selected that post as an answer.